# VBA UBound for Split function vs UBound for String array

Tags: vba, split

When I use the UBound function on the Split function it returns n-1 (n is the length of the array) but when I use the UBound function on an array of length 1, it returns n.

```
Dim arr1(1) As String, arr2 as Variant

arr1(0) = "test"
Debug.print "UBound(arr1): " & UBound(arr1)

arr2 = Split("test1/test2", "/")
Debug.print "UBound(arr2): " & UBound(arr2)
```

Returns:

```
UBound(arr1): 1
UBound(arr2): 1
```

arr1 has a length of 1 and arr2 has a length of 2 but UBound returns 1 for both?

Comment: Doesn't arr1 has a length of 2 since arrays are zero based?

Comment: `Ubound` is not the "length" (necessarily) but the maximum index of a dimension of an array.

Comment: @TimWilliams I agree. I should have better phrased, removed the comment now.

Comment: ...so UBound is only equal to the length of any array dimension when the lower bound is 1 (and it typically is zero unless you're getting your array using a multi-cell range's .Value property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You are not sure what is going on with Arrays use Watches

[image: ![enter image description here]

Both arrays have 2 elements, on (0) and (1) position, that's why You see in both cases answer: 1.